# MySQL Date between query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Why `BETWEEN '2020-02-22 00:00:00' AND '2020-02-22 23:59:59'` is working (getting Data)?

AND why `BETWEEN '2020-02-22' AND '2020-02-22'` is not working (Not getting Data)?

Edited: Got it. I forgot to add `date(created_at)` instead of `created_at`

Comment: Can you plz show us what have you tried that we could look?

Comment: I'm trying to get today's data from the table and I'm using daterangepicker to change dates.

Comment: Because none of your timestamps has a value of `'2020-02-22'`

Comment: @forpas, Yes you're correct.

Comment: `'2020-02-22'` is shorthand for `'2020-02-22 00:00:00'`, so the failing attempt was checking for _just midnight_.  Note also that `BETWEEN` is "inclusive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `whereBetween` method

It verifies that a column's value is between two values.

Expl

```
$from = date('2018-01-01');
$to = date('2018-05-02');

Model::whereBetween('dateColumn', [$from, $to])->get();
```

Or

```
Model::where('dateColumn', '>=', $from)->where('dateColumn', '<=', $to)->get();
```

Comment: It's working. I also found that I didn't add `date(created_at)` instead of `created_at` after doing this my code is working fine.
Anyway Thanks a lot